# Java. TDD. Возможно ли проверить присвоение null при помощи assertThat(is)

Tags: java, null, test-driven-development

Если я хочу в тесте проверить что какой-то объект получил значение null а конструкция `assertThat` `is` не работает с `null`  как быть?

Я пишу:

```
assertThat(result, is(null));
```

И это не работает(((
Это как-то противоречит TDD подходу?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этого случая есть специальный метод nullValue():

```
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.is;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.nullValue;

assertThat(result, is(nullValue()));
```